# DCF of Arbitrary Dates Cash Flows

Tags: fixed-income

I am having a problem understanding discounted cash flows. I appreciate your patience and help.
Lets say I have a bond that I want to price.

```
Par: $1000
Coupon Rate: %5.0
YTM: %5.0
Frequency: Semi-Annual – 2 (Paid on: 6/30/20XX,12/31/20XX)
Settlement Date: 8/15/2013
Maturity Date: 12/31/2014


12/31/2013  6/30/2014   12/31/2014  6/30/2014   12/31/2014
      25        25        25          25           1025
```

This is the formula I know used to discount cash flows. CF/(1+r/n)^a, where, as I understand it, a=n*t. My question is when valuing bonds I have seen people using the typical a=1,2,3,4,…,n*t
I  have also seen formula’s where a=.5,1,1.5,2,2.5 when discounting semi-annual cash flows.
I have also seen people using # of days a=280 for example when the cash flow is some arbitrary date.

For such a simple formula, this unbelievably complicated. Can someone please just explain to me how to find “a” . Is there a comprehensive formula I could use that can discount any cash flow no matter what the date is? Eg. Today is 03/14/2009 and the CF is due on 07/2/2010 for the same info above what would a be?

Comment: Really Sorry Matt. I am still new to the forum. I promise to go back and check off one's where my question was answered. Appreciate your patience and help.

Comment: The conversion between the dates and the year fraction is determined by the day counting convention you use. 
The following document explains this in more details:
http://marchioro.webs.com/White-papers/intro-fixed-income-derivatives.pdf